# The memory increases due to an instance of an activity

Tags: android, memory

I have an application that creates a service. When you exit and re-enter the service running, the memory increases.
I've analyzed the file "hprof" with MAT:

*"One instance of "com.yulis.PantallaPrincipal" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x406bea70" occupies 557.432 (17,08%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "com.yulis.Multimedia" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x406bea70""*

If I go out and go into the application several times, increasing the number of instances.
One class receives a "context" of a class activity and data capture service class that class. Could this be the problem?

How do I prevent this?

Comment: MAT will show you the references back to these objects, so you can track down what is causing them not to get garbage collected.

Comment: So far, leaked context is the most popular culprit for memory leaks. [Check out this topic](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: The service maintains the instance of the activity. How do you avoid this?